# Can someone share how to merge multiple excel files in automation anywhere. I would like to create my own and not use a bot store?

Tags: automation, rpa

I couldn't find any command which would help get all cells in a excel. Also, I couldn't find any command which would then paste all cells from one excel to another

Answer (score 0):

First of all, there isn't a simple merge AA command that will just do what you're wanting. If you want something pre-built then you would have to find one from the bot store. However, what you're describing is quite simple to do inside of AA.

You'll have to start by using the "Open Spreadsheet" command to open both in Excel. Then use the "Get Cells" command to select the ones you need to move. Then use the "Keystrokes" command to perform a [CTRL DOWN]c[CTRL UP] to copy those selected cells and then another "Keystrokes" command [CTRL DOWN]v[CTRL UP] to paste them into the second spreadsheet.

I would strongly suggest logging into AA's [provided documentation](https://docs.automationanywhere.com/bundle/enterprise-v2019.02/page/topics/aae-client/bot-creator/commands/cloud-excel-command.html) for the Excel command. Also, it sounds like reading the basic [how to create a bot](https://docs.automationanywhere.com/bundle/enterprise-v2019.02/page/topics/aae-client/bot-creator/using-the-workbench/cloud-create-a-bot.html) might be another good place to start.

Comment: Thanks. I decided to move forward with a macro and then use the Run macro command

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own Metabot to achieve this. Below is the quick code snippet that you can use -

```
using Spire.Xls; 
using System; 
using System.Collections.Generic; 
using System.Linq; 
using System.Text; 

namespace unmerge_the_cells 
{ 
    class Program 
    { 
        static void Main(string[] args) 
        { 
            Workbook book = new Workbook(); 
            book.LoadFromFile(@"C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\unmerge.xlsx"); 
            Worksheet sheet = book.Worksheets[0]; 
            sheet.Range["A2"].UnMerge(); 
            book.SaveToFile("consequence.xlsx", ExcelVersion.Version2010); 
        } 
    } 
}
```

Don't forget to install spire.xls library for C#